# Shell script to find files with similar names

Tags: shell

I have a directory with multiple files in the form of:

```
file001_a
file002_a
file002_b
file003_a
```

Using a shell script, I was wondering what the easiest way would be to list all files within this directory that have duplicates in the first 7 letters; ie the output above would be:

```
file002_a
file002_b
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls -1 *_*| awk '{fn=substr($0,1,7);a[fn]=a[fn]" "substr($0,8)}END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}'
```

Comment: it hurts my eyes, but does everything i want it to do - thank you! :)